# show text depend on which menu is clicked

Tags: wordpress, text, hyperlink, menu

I would like to ask a question as a newbie. I have a WordPress site and i have to menu links that load the same page

```
Menu
   Link 1 
      page
   Link 2 
      page
```

Now i would like if the user go to page from link 1 to show a text`(lets say This i link 1)` 
If the user go to page from link 2 to show a text`(lets say This i link 2)`.

Can you guide me please how can I do that? Shall I use php? 
Should I track somehow the url and make If the url contains `(link 1 )` show text?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the breadcrumbs for this,

- You can find plugins for this in Wordpress or write custom code. For example,

  function get_breadcrumb() {
  echo 'Home';
  if (is_category() || is_single()) {
      echo "  »  ";
      the_category(' • ');
          if (is_single()) {
              echo "   »   ";
              the_title();
          }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
      echo "  »  ";
      echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
      echo "  »  Search Results for... ";
      echo '"*';
      echo the_search_query();
      echo '*"';
    }
  }

Hope this will helps you.
For more details. Please visit [WordPress – How to Display Breadcrumb without Plugin](https://www.codexworld.com/wordpress-how-to-display-breadcrumb-without-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that with a hash code and jquery, but thank you very much @Sunil Dora for your reply :-)